# Vertically align UIButton with UITextField text

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout, uitextview, nslayoutconstraint

I want to add a "read more"-button at the end of the textview text. The text is in a `UITextView` and the button is a `UIButton`. So first I would like to make the button align vertically with the textview last line.

[image]

I'm getting the size of the text views text container in `layoutSubviews` (this is happening in a `UICollectionReusableView`):

```
let containerSize = descriptionTextView.layoutManager.usedRectForTextContainer(descriptionTextView.textContainer).size
showAllButtonHeight.constant = containerSize.height
```

I'm using Autolayout. I have a constraint (`showAllButtonHeight`) defining the y-value of the button defined like this:

[image]

How can i make the button align perfectly with the text? Or is there a better way of making this kind of "read more"-button?